# Undefined Error in my project

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery know's some basic things. In my project I coded some Ajax jquery to retrieve data and show in html. All run's fine when page  load's first time. When I refresh page or move to same link it show's Page Says Undefined error . It is not fixed that this undefined error comes on first time refresh .Some time it works fine and appear on 4 -5 refresh continuously.  Some body please let me know what to do with this one. Here I am not posting code because there are 8-10 pages of jquery .

Comment: No code to see, no way to solve the problem. I can give you a billion guesses on what's returning 'undefined'.

Comment: The error gives you a line number, where your code broke. Try working back from there to see, what went wrong.

Comment: Try opening the `Network` tab in the Chrome dev tools, and explain to us what is happening there.

Comment: It sounds like a timing problem. How do you change your page in your jQuery? My guess is that you don't wait until the ajax call is finished to change your html, and when the asynchronous thing takes a little longer, the code crashes

Comment: Hay somebody who given a reference site deleted comment. I gone through that link but doesn't get it's relation with my error and how to rectify through that link

Comment: hay Jonas , you are right undefined error occur when one ajax call is finished and page is refreshed that crashe the code. Can you tell me how can I correct this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your error:**

http://krishayak.com/User/UserHome.aspx/LiveInnerCommTick Origin http://www.krishayak.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Solution**

Use JSONP,  add ?callback=? to the end of the URL in your ajax requests like this:

```
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://krishayak.com/User/UserHome.aspx/Firsttime?callback=?',
                 data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
              success: FirstTime,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
```

Comment: Lot of Thanks , as I said earlier I am new in jquery, I don't know about JSONP, add &callback=? . Can you please tell me how I can implement your suggestion and in which position

Comment: See my code example above, in the url: I add &callback=? in the end, try to do this in all the URL's that you have in each $ajax({....}) request

Comment: I copy paste , your code and implemented  but it'snot working firstly It was loading on first load but now it's not working on page load also. You can check on the site

Comment: Dear Sbml, it doesn't work replaced the  jsfiddle code with initial.js,

Comment: No change, showing undefined on pageload , how can I check jquery error  as you checked and told me.

Comment: You have more errors in the page. In InnerComments,js you need to change the URL's and add ?callback=?

Comment: You can see your errors in your browser console. Use firefox or Chrome, click in your mouse right button and choose Inspect Element. Then go to the console tab and refresh your page. Learn to use this tool

Comment: You have a syntax error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in Default.aspx:3 so check this to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36875/discussion-between-kumal-and-sbml)